# Cannot write to sector - boot Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, write

So I was in an airport working and I closed my laptop. When I brought it back up again, my screen was black so I kill switched. Now when I boot, I get "cannot write to sector".

Comment: Is that the first message you get? Linux should not try to write to the disk before the first volume is mounted. Until then there should be a lot of messages. In any case you need a bootable Linux on CD/DVD or USB stick in order to repair the installation (or detect hardware problems). It is not necessary but might help to use the distro you have installed for that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your laptop specifications like company name etc.You could try out these options:

1.press `Esc` key while booting and do a Memory test or Run test.

2.Remove battery and restart the Laptop

3.This is bit *risky* but you could try it.Try shaking your laptop or moving it down but not to the floor.

**Reason for these options is**:I tried all these options and all have worked.It might be due to the harddisk sector head which might be misplaced.I'm not sure about it but you could try out these options.